# Allow user requesting multiple virtual machines from a pool in Ovirt/RHEV

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, rhev

In RHEV with a user I can request a virtual machine from a pool but if I try to get a second virtual machine, fails with this message:

> User is already attached to this VM-Pool.

There is a way to allow a user to get multiple virtual machines from a pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not how pools work, the whole idea is to have a pool for a set of users, each taking an available VM from this pool. If there is a valid use case, you can always contact support and file a feature request

Comment: Thanks dyasny, I really don't have a valid use case :)